# Background image does not appear on the phone screen

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am making an app using ionic, however the background image does not appear no matter what I try. I checked previous questions but non of the solution worked for me. 
This is my css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("img/national day.png");
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    /*position: relative;*/
}
```

I know that the path is correct for sure because its there in the frames when I debug using chrome. There is an img file in my css directory.Why isn't the picture appearing though
fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y04jpe0h/

Comment: why don't you try your image name without space something like **national_day.png**

Comment: I did but no use, ty though

Comment: have u try change with image path /img/ OR ../img/  instant of img/

Comment: @channasmcs yes I tried different paths and chrome debugger tells me when a path is not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't know why it is not working in the end so I just added the background image to the pane and it got displayed. Remains a mystery..

Answer (score 1):

Add this part of CSS in your code

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
```

Hope that works!

Comment: It didn't work, sadly, I don't understand the problem ;/

Comment: are you using media queries? can you post a fiddle so that we can debug it easily

Comment: no im not using them, the fiddle is posted in the question but i didnt include the angular file because its big

Comment: are the image and css files in different folders? works for me https://jsfiddle.net/y04jpe0h/1/

Comment: in my css file, I have a folder called img which contains the image mentioned above.

Comment: Are you using usb debugging ? on what phone?

Comment: I'm using chrome debugger

Comment: can you use chrome debugger without a device connected?

Comment: I'm actually testing on chrome device emulator. there's no need to connect a device

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I Removed the background size 100% 100% property.

```
{
    background: url("img/national day.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried it but I still get a white background image :/ Thank you for your time though

Comment: Yes I just did but.. :(

Answer (score 1):

At first to access folder img you have to put :
    background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
because img folder is not into css folder.
Second make sure you have the image in img folder because i didn't find it into fiddle so it try logo .png and it works.

Comment: I created a folder img inside the css folder with the img